# Find object with in class using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return the item that has the profile ID I send. So in order to do this I will need to loop through all of the Items -> WebProproperties -> profile. The Class structure is at the end of the question.

I would rather use LINQ than create a nested `foreach`. I have been trying to get this to work for more than an hour now. I am stuck.

My first idea was to simply use `where`. But that doesn't work because you need to have something on the other side that needs to equal.

```
this.Accounts.items.Where(a => a.webProperties.Where(b => b.profiles.Where(c => c.id == pSearchString)) ).FirstOrDefault();
```

My second idea was to try using `Exists` which I don't have much experience with:

```
Item test =  from item in this.Accounts.items.Exists(a => a.webProperties.Exists(b => b.profiles.Exists(c => c.id == pSearchString))) select item;
```

This doesn't work either:

> Could not find an implementation of query pattern for source type 'Bool'

```
    public RootObject Accounts {get; set;}

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public int totalResults { get; set; }
        public int startIndex { get; set; }
        public int itemsPerPage { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class WebProperty
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string internalWebPropertyId { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string websiteUrl { get; set; }
        public List<Profile> profiles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<WebProperty> webProperties { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) to determine existence. Also, note that many of the extension methods have overloads which take a predicate, including `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
this.Accounts.items.FirstOrDefault(a => a.webProperties
      .Any(b => b.profiles
          .Any(c => c.id == pSearchString)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `.Any()` operation I think. This will return true/false for whether there are any items matching your query.

For example:

```
if (this.Accounts.Items.Any(i=>i.webProperties.Any(wp=>wp.profiles.Any(p=>p.id == MySearchId)));
```

EDIT: You have full answer (was posted while I was composing mine) and as pointed out in comments my answer isn't actually returning your found item, just letting you know whether there is one. You can rework the first `.Any` to be a `.FirstOrDefault` to get that match.
E.g.

`var result = this.Accounts.Items.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.webProperties.Any(wp=>wp.profiles.Any(p=>p.id == MySearchId)))`

Comment: The principle is sound so +1 but you are not returning the item, just checking if one exists.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Must pay more attention to question ... yes, he wanted to return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned code.

```
var abc = rr.items.Where(p => p.webProperties.Any(c => c.profiles.Any(d => d.id == "1"))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just for your reference, your class should look like:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public int startIndex { get; set; }
    public int itemsPerPage { get; set; }
    private List<Item> _items=new List<Item>();

    public List<Item> items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally yes the class should look like that, but the class is loaded using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject.  The data is the JSON response from the Google Analtyics API.   I chose to leave it basic as I was unsure what JsonConvert.DeserializeObject could handle.